# Trouble reading a .txt file and storing into an array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been given a .txt file with a specific structure: each line has a String with 5 characters but with a random number of lines, and we should read the file and store it as we want.
I've tried doing it with a linked list and it worked just fine but as the size of the file grew up, the time it took to execute was too long. Since then i've been trying to store the Strings into an array of strings, so everything would be stored contiguously in memory. When executing, i get a segmentation fault error and i have no idea why. The code goes as follows:

```
int nLines (char *path)
{
    int answer = 0;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(path,"r");
    char line[6];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp))
    {
        answer++;
    }

    return answer;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int numberLines = nLines(argv[1]);

    char **storage = malloc(numberLines * 6 * sizeof(char));

    if(storage != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        char line [6];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp))
        {
            strcpy(storage[i], line);
            i++;
        }
    }

    free(storage);
}
```

The first function is supposed to return the number of lines there is in the file. With this information, i'm trying to allocate memory equal to the number of strings * the size of each string since i know before hand this value. I'm imagining the problem comes from the line:

```
char **storage = malloc (numberLines * 6 *sizeof(char));
```

I haven't touched C in a long time and i'm kinda rusty with the whole pointers and memory stuff. Can someone help please. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a special reason for you having two lines which seem to me to be semantically identical `fp = fopen(path,"r");` ?

Comment: @Yunnosch no, i guess there isn't. I just didn't want to do all in the main function. And i guess i should do fclose(fp) as well. Thanks for the help. The segmentation fault problem stills remains.

Comment: If you use `**storage`, after you allocated space for `**storage`, you have to allocate space (7 bytes each pointer) for each `*storage`

Comment: `char **storage = malloc(numberLines * 6 * sizeof(char));` shall be `char **storage = malloc(numberLines * sizeof(char *))`;

Comment: what is `sizeof(* char)` and what language it is

Comment: @P__J__, an error! :p

Comment: The functions that counts the lines should close the file: `fclose(fp);`

Comment: If you know the record length you might use ftell and fseek (`fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
int lengthOfFile = ftell(fp);`) to have the length of the file! and then you might use `fseek` to move the file at the beginning.

Comment: @P__J__ i'm not sure i understand what's happening inside the while block and why it should work

Comment: The variabile `storage[i]` is not allocated. That is!!!

Comment: you should comment the answer if you write about my one

Comment: @P__J__, yours? ... I think only to solve the issue, not to have a race!!! :D

Comment: @SirJoBlack I comment OPs comment where I am linked. So I wrote if it about by answer - he should comment  my answer. Otherwise I do not understand why I was linked there. Do you disagree that the comments should be below the correct posts? What race do you mean?

Comment: @P__J__, Excuse me. I've misunderstud!

Comment: I refers my comment not to your code, but to the code where's the comment!

Comment: This counts the number beforehand. If you want to truly have an on-line algorithm, (the size is unknown,) a `vector`-type object where one reallocates geometrically increasing capacity is probably the way to go. One has another `fopen` in `nLines` that's probably going to need to be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

your allocation is wrong

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    size_t numberLines = 0;

    char **storage = NULL; 

    char line [8];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp))
    {
        storage = realloc(storage, (numberLines + 1) * sizeof(*storage));
        storage[numberLines] = malloc(8);
        strcpy(storage[numlines++], line);
    }
/* ... */
}
```

you need to allocate space for the pointers, then space for the strings. It is demo only and you should implement the correct error handling (memory and file).

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to truly have an on-line algorithm, one isn't going to have the number of lines available. The idiomatic way to have a contiguous dynamic container is to reallocate geometrically increasing capacity, like [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). `C` doesn't have that type built-in, but it's worth the extra code if one uses it a lot. For example, this reads from `stdin` until `EOF` and uses a Fibonacci sequence as it's capacities.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** One line of maximum 5 `char` plus 1 `NUL`. */
struct Line { char str[6]; };

/** A dynamic line array. */
struct LineArray {
    struct Line *data; /* data -> (c0 < c1 || c0 == c1 == max_size) */
    size_t capacity, next_capacity; /* !data -> !size, data -> size<=capacity */
    size_t size;
};

/** Ensures `min_capacity` of `a`. Return success, otherwise, `errno` will be
 set: `realloc` or `ERANGE` -- tried allocating more then can fit in `size_t`
 or `realloc` doesn't follow [IEEE Std 1003.1-2001
 ](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html). */
static int reserve(struct LineArray *const a, const size_t min_capacity) {
    size_t c0, c1;
    struct Line *data;
    const size_t max_size = (size_t)-1 / sizeof(struct Line *);
    assert(a);
    if(!a->data) {
        if(!min_capacity) return 1;
        c0 = 8, c1 = 13;
    } else {
        if(min_capacity <= a->capacity) return 1;
        c0 = a->capacity, c1 = a->next_capacity;
    }
    if(min_capacity > max_size) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    assert(c0 < c1); /* Fibonacci: c0 ^= c1, c1 ^= c0, c0 ^= c1, c1 += c0. */
    while(c0 < min_capacity) {
        size_t temp = c0 + c1; c0 = c1; c1 = temp;
        if(c1 > max_size || c1 < c0) c1 = max_size;
    }
    if(!(data = realloc(a->data, c0 * sizeof *a->data)))
        { if(!errno) errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    a->data = data;
    a->capacity = c0;
    a->next_capacity = c1;
    return 1;
}

/** Adds one to the size of `a` and returns it (`push_back`.) Exceptional
 return null and `errno` is `realloc` or `ERANGE`. */
static struct Line *new_line(struct LineArray *const a) {
    assert(a);
    if(a->size >= (size_t)-1) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; } /* Unlikely. */
    if(!reserve(a, a->size + 1)) return 0; /* (Less) unlikely. */
    return a->data + a->size++;
}

/** Destructor. */
static void linearray_(struct LineArray *const a) {
    assert(a);
    free(a->data);
    a->data = 0, a->capacity = a->next_capacity = a->size = 0;
}

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct LineArray storage = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    struct Line *s, *s_end;
    size_t l = 0, line_len;
    char line[7] = "";
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* `line` must be capable of storing the "*[,5]\n\0". */
    assert(sizeof line == sizeof ((struct Line *)0)->str + 1);

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        l++;
        line_len = strlen(line);
        assert(line_len && line_len < sizeof line);
        /* Too long. */
        if(line[line_len - 1] != '\n') { errno = ERANGE; goto catch; }
        /* Cut off the trailing new-line. */
        line[line_len-- - 1] = '\0';
        /* Store `line`. */
        if(!(s = new_line(&storage))) goto catch;
        strcpy(s->str, line);
    }
    if(ferror(stdin)) goto catch;
    /* Print all. */
    for(s = storage.data, s_end = s + storage.size; s < s_end; s++)
        printf("stored: %s\n", s->str);
    success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    goto finally;
catch:
    perror("Error");
    fprintf(stderr, "On line %lu: \"%s\".\n", (unsigned long)l, line);
finally:
    linearray_(&storage);
    return success;
}
```